# SSL Certificate Pain Points

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am a graduate student researching SSL certificates for a thesis project.  The scope relates specifically to the pain points experienced by consultants with regards to SSL certs, specifically what aspects of SSL certificates are currently problems and areas of improvement that need to be made.  I was wondering if anyone would be interested in providing some thoughts, or if you'd like to speak more, please let me know.

Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I'm sorry, but this site is intended for Q&A, not for discussion.

Comment: I suggest you take your question to security.stackexchange.com. But please first look for the existing answers to similar questions before asking a new one.